# Fill left and right of table cell with horizontal line aligned at vertical middle of cell

Tags: tables, line

Right now the following code achieves the desired result:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
1. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & 10\tabularnewline
2. & \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textendash \textemdash{}
`` \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textendash \textemdash{} & 20\tabularnewline
3. & \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textendash \textemdash{}
`` \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textendash \textemdash{} & 30\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

Desired result:

[image]

However, the problem with the above code is that I have to manually figure out the appropriate number of "\textemdash"s to put in.

I am wondering if there is a command that automatically achieves a similar result, i.e. fills in the remaining space in the left and right of a table cell with a horizontal line.

I've tried \hrulefill but the horizontal line produced is at the bottom (rather than vertical middle) of the cell:

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
1. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & 10\tabularnewline
2. & \hrulefill{} `` \hrulefill & 20\tabularnewline
3. & \hrulefill{} `` \hrulefill & 30\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can measure the width of the widest element and use that in a `p{<len>}` column specification, and then use `\xfill`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Taken from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xhfill/xhfill-doc.tex
\newcommand{\xfill}[2][.7ex]{{%
  \dimen0=#2\advance\dimen0 by #1
  \mbox{}\leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth -#1\hfill%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
  1. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & 10 \\
  2. & \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textendash \textemdash{}
    `` \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textendash \textemdash{} & 20 \\
  3. & \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textendash \textemdash{}
    `` \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textemdash \textendash \textemdash{} & 30
\end{tabular}

\newlength{\widestlength}
\settowidth{\widestlength}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}

\begin{tabular}{ c p{\widestlength} c }
  1. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & 10 \\
  2. & \xfill{.4pt} `` \xfill{.4pt} & 20 \\
  3. & \xfill{.4pt} `` \xfill{.4pt} & 30
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

You can automate the process of finding the widest element using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>]{<stuff>}` together with [`collcell`](//ctan.org/pkg/collcell)'s `\collectcell<cmd>`...`\endcollectcell` column specification. The latter passes the cell entry to a single-argument macro `<cmd>` for processing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xfill}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height \dimexpr.7ex+#1\relax depth -.7ex\hfill\kern\z@%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{eqparbox,collcell}
\newcommand{\tagname}{}
\newcommand{\samewidth}[1]{%
  \eqmakebox[\tagname][c]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tagname}{lorem}
\begin{tabular}{ c >{\collectcell\samewidth}c<{\endcollectcell} c }
  1. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & 10 \\
  2. & \xfill{.4pt} `` \xfill{.4pt} & 20 \\
  3. & \xfill{.4pt} `` \xfill{.4pt} & 30
\end{tabular}

\renewcommand{\tagname}{ipsum}
\begin{tabular}{ c >{\collectcell\samewidth}c<{\endcollectcell} c }
  1. & Lorem ipsum dolor sit & 10 \\
  2. & \xfill{.4pt} `` \xfill{.4pt} & 20 \\
  3. & \xfill{.4pt} `` \xfill{.4pt} & 30
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The above example requires at least two compilations with every change in the cell entries (and on the first go).